# Postgresql fatal error

Tags: postgresql

I am using postgresql. By mistake i gave permission to the postgresql folder through the command

```
chmod -R 777 /var/lib/postgresql/
```

Now that when i am trying to connect to postgresql it is giving me the following error.

```
The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output:
2013-09-19 07:21:48 GMT FATAL:  data directory
"/var/lib/postgresql/8.4/main" has group or world access 2013-09-19
07:21:48 GMT DETAIL:  Permissions should be u=rwx (0700).
```

tried restarting postgresql server through command

```
/etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

but getting the same error.

what shall i do?

Comment: Doesn’t the message already tell you what you should do …?

Comment: chmod -R 700 /var/lib/postgresql/ ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PostgreSQL requires exclusive access to the files in the data directory.  This is fixable depending on your operating system by using `chmod 700` on the data directory or by right-clicking, and selecting various options on Windows.